# Subtracting minutes from Boost ptime

Tags: c++, datetime, boost

I'm trying to clamp a posix_time::ptime instance into 5 minute intervals.

For example:

```
1.  10:31:00 -> 10:30:00 
2.  11:59:00 -> 11:55:00
```

My understanding is that one can subtract time from a ptime based on a period. The code below however seems to increment the time not decrement it.

```
#include <iostream>

#include "boost/date_time.hpp"
using namespace boost::posix_time;

boost::posix_time::ptime make(int h, int m, int s)
{
   return boost::posix_time::ptime
      (boost::gregorian::date(1900,1,1),
      boost::posix_time::time_duration(h,m,s,0));
}

int main()
{
   boost::posix_time::ptime t = make(22,2,0);

   int extra_mins = t.time_of_day().minutes() % 5;

   t -= boost::posix_time::minutes(extra_mins);

   if (t.time_of_day().minutes() != 0)
      std::cout << "ERROR";

   return 0;
}
```

I'm not able to immediately see the error, as it seems to be correctly decrement a duration from a time point.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what you mean with

> I'm not able to immediately see the error, as it seems to be correctly decrement a duration from a time point.

I'm also not able to see the error, because the behaviour is what I expect. I don't, of course, know what you're expecting. Here goes:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "boost/date_time.hpp"
#include "boost/date_time/posix_time/posix_time_io.hpp"

using namespace boost::posix_time;

boost::posix_time::ptime make(int h, int m, int s)
{
   return boost::posix_time::ptime
      (boost::gregorian::date(1900,1,1),
      boost::posix_time::time_duration(h,m,s,0));
}

int main()
{
   boost::posix_time::ptime t = make(22,2,0);
   std::cout << "made: " << t << "\n";

   int extra_mins = t.time_of_day().minutes() % 5;
   std::cout << "extra_mins: " << extra_mins << "\n";

   t -= boost::posix_time::minutes(extra_mins);
   std::cout << "t - extra_mins: " << t << "\n";

   if (t.time_of_day().minutes() != 0)
      std::cout << "ERROR";
}
```

Output:

```
made: 1900-Jan-01 22:02:00
extra_mins: 2
t - extra_mins: 1900-Jan-01 22:00:00
```

Which looks pretty okay to me. See ti **[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1f5b533b90c93659)** too.